# Reset a BMS chip - maybe

Tags: batteries

I've got a Fujitsu Stylistic Q572. It's quite a nice windows tablet but the battery is dead - one of the cells is 0 volts. A new battery costs more than the tablet is worth but it's a functioning computer and I'd prefer not to send it to landfill.

I opened the battery pack and replaced the 2 cells with fully-charged new cells. (Yes I know I'm taking my life in my hands by fiddling with Li cells.)

There's a battery management pcb in the battery pack that contains a MAX1788 chip.

I can see the power going into the battery management pcb but none of it gets passed to the Q572.

My guess is that the MAX1788 thinks the cells have died and doesn't even try to connect it.

Is that a reasonable guess? Can the MAX1788 be so stupid? The MAX1788 is "obsolete" and I can't find a manual for it. AFAIK, in general, the main processor can talk to BMS chips and "reset" them. But I can't find a command to do that in Windows or the BIOS.

Am I being foolish trying to "fix" the BMS chip? What Windows/BIOS command should I use? Is there a hardware process to reset the chip?

What can I try next?

Comment: Quick google shows that you need to reprogram MAX1788. Looks like this program could help you: https://be2works.com/

Comment: Good find @Morris   The Max77818 obsolete EVAL gives some clues to theory of operation like "coulomb counter with the long-term stability of a voltage-based fuel gauge"  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max77818.pdf

Comment: Another backup is a 5V USB battery bank.    or Battery for FUJITSU STYLISTIC Q572-W8-001 7.2 V 4800 mAh LiPo

Price: €19.90

Comment: Aliexpress has the USB-UART cards for ~$7 shipped  CP2112

Comment: Thank you all. I hate smart chips that lock me out of my own computer! Unfortunately, the that €19.90 battery company doesn't ship to the UK.

Comment: The be2works app looks great. That's good googling. I'm not keen on sending my "registration data" to an unknown Eastern European site. It seems to suggest that the MAX1788 communicates via SPI whereas that datasheet is for a MAX77818 which is I2C - but it gives an idea of what MAX1788 might be doing. You'd think the MAX1788 datasheet would be available _somewhere_.

Comment: Some more googling says that MAX1788 datasheet was not open to general public, you would need to sign an NDA to get it. 
I've found more links, try them:
https://www.laptopu.ro/
https://newsmartsafe.com/industry-news/bms-reset-tool